# What strategy for committing AppName.xcodeproj bundles to SVN?

Tags: iphone

Each time I do a commit in Xcode I notice that the AppName.xcodeproj file/bundle has been modified. The modifications are obviously important although I don't have enough experience with Xcode to understand them.

What strategy should I use for this? Do I simply commit these changes each time? It's no big deal, it's just that it will appear in SVN history. I'm assuming that I don't add an 'ignore' SVN proprty for this file/bundle, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That project folder contains the metadata for your project, so it certainly needs to be included in source control. There are a some user-specific files you can leave out, though. My `.gitignore` includes these two entries

```
*.mode2v3
*.pbxuser
```

But it won't hurt to leave them in, since they don't affect anything when other users open the project.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. It's mostly these two files that changes occur in. So it's really the project.pbxproj that contains the project metadata? I think I'll add an 'ignore' to the user.mode2v3 and the user.pbxuser files. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have followed [this article](http://shanesbrain.net/2008/7/9/using-xcode-with-git) for every project and it helps me extremely well. You have to commit two files: .gitignore and .gitattibutes first in order for [GitX](http://gitx.frim.nl/) to have effect.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to add build directory in order not to include temporary binaries into the repository.